# ul>li*5[TAB] not working on WebStorm

Tags: ide, webstorm, emmet

I am new to react and WebStorm.
I used to using Emmet.
but some of the Emmet operation seems not working well on WebStorm.

How to solve it?

my WebStorm version is 11.0.1

Comment: This seems extremely unclear, can you clarify what issues you are running into?

Answer (score 0):

@Tiper You may need to update your version. Also, remember to hit tab after typing that out :

```
ul>li*5 then tab
```

Will create :

```
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

Works fine in mine and I'm using version 11.0.3

Comment: So it's not supported by 11.0.1?

Comment: @Tiper not 100% sure. But I do recommend updating to 11.0.3 as it does work in it.